# Fading a border (css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

Here is a picture of what I am working with:

[image]

I need the borders below the vertical menu bar (on the left) to fade out (the one going up and the one going down).  How would I make these two borders fade out?  It seems kind of blocky now.  I prefer not to use JavaScript but I will probably do what is necessary (I'm trying to make the site as light weight as possible).

**EDIT**

By fade, I do mean over space, not time.

Comment: are you trying to animate the fade with css only?

Comment: I think he is talking about a static fadeout to make it visually appealing.

Comment: This question would be a lot more useful to future visitors if it explained the problem without needing a link. Once you fix the problem on your page, the link will no longer display the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two fade-out images as `background-image`

```
li.edge_top, li.edge_bottom {
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li.edge_top {
  background-image: url:('fadeout_top.png');
}

li.edge_bottom {
  background-image: url:('fadeout_bottom.png');
}
```

Comment: how big of an image should I make to prevent having to load too big of a resolution of an image (could be a waste) or too small (low quality)?

Comment: You make it exactly that tall as you want it to appear on screen. You can just take the height of the element as a measure. The width should be the same as the border-width of your menu elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a bunch of 1px tall blocks with successively lighter border-right colors.

(Assume you mean "fade" as in over space, not time)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the new CSS3 `border-right-image` attribute (http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) with a tall gradient PNG.  However, this isn't going to be widely supported in most browsers.  You're probably better off creating an image with the right gradient and setting it as the `background-image` on the `.edge_bottom` and `.edge_top` css classes (be sure to remove the existing border from those classes, too)

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 gradients to the rescue!

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtEmC/1/)**

**Note:** Gradients are only set up for Firefox. I can't test Webkit, but it should be pretty much the same.

Comment: Can you do that with borders too?

Comment: @Alp: That was I looked at initially, and found the implementation to be [fairly limited](http://jsfiddle.net/G7Jdx/).

Comment: Thanks for giving an example. Yes, looks like using border-image is the CSS3-way to go.

Answer (score -1):

This will remove it, these pseudo elements are not supported in older browsers

```
ul.vertical_menu > li:first-child {
    border-right:none;
}
ul.vertical_menu > li:last-child {
    border-right:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ceb5/

Comment: He does not want to remove them.

Comment: I want them there.  I just want them to kind of fade as they leave from the menu...

Comment: give a background and align it to the right, as the border cannot be a gradient, this class may has right margin as -1px so the background fits to other borders